# Browserifying libraries that were themselves browserified: relative paths error

Tags: browserify

I want to use a library that was build using browserify. The library built correctly and works fine when it is used by itself.

Now that **built** library is in my vendors/ directory, and I try to require it in my new application:

```
var myLib = require('./vendors/myLib');
```

When I try to browserify my application, it complains that it can't find some of the internal `require` statements inside that library:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../utils/logger' from '/myApp/vendor'
```

Browserify seems to be trying to re-build the lib from the wrong directory. How can I fix this?

---

More specifics:

The lib looks like this:

```
myLib
 │  app.js
 │
 ├──models
 │    model.js
 │
 ├──utils
      logger.js
```

app `requires` model, and model `requires` logger using `require('../utils/logger')`.

This is then build into myLib.js (`browserify app.js --standalone myLib > myLib.js`).

So far, so good, myLib works fine.

In my new application, I put myLib.js in the /vendor directory, `require` it as listed at top, and get the error that Browserify can't find '../utils/logger'.

In this situation I *do* control myLib, so could change it if absolutely necessary, but it's another project in the company and I'd prefer not to if necessary. However, I see [at least one other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359794/browserify-cant-deal-with-package) on SO where someone is clearly having the same problem with a bower-installed third-party library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be [pretty borked](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/374).

Here are a few options:

- Run [derequire](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/derequire) on `myLib` before consuming.
- Try browserifying your app like so:

  ```js
  browserify({
    entries: ['./entry'],
    noParse: ['/abs/path/to/vendors/myLib.js'],
  })
  ```

  If it doesn't work, try it without the extension in the `noParse` value.
- Minify `myLib` before consuming it.

Comment: This is incredible. The referenced lib has mere 52 stars, but 200k downloads per month. This is a functionality that is basically one of the most fundamental mechanisms that is needed when publishing libraries out there, and yet, this is "the way" to do it :D

Answer (score 0):

aaaah, i finally got it working. using the standalone option of browserify along with gulp-derequire did the trick! yay!