# How to bundle CommonJS modules into a single UMD library file?

Tags: javascript, browserify, commonjs

I'm writing a JS library and organizing the code in a hierarchy of CommonJS modules connected with `require` calls. Then in addition there are also external dependencies (like Underscore).

How can I bundle all my library modules into a single file (CommonJS+AMD) excluding the external dependencies which should remain as `require` calls?

I've experimented with Browserify and came close with `--standalone` and `--external` but when using Browserify again on the application that is using this bundled library it gets confused with the remaining `require` calls inside the bundled lib. And when I get rid of them with something like Derequire it will also strip out the `require` calls to external dependencies.

I tried to figure out how other libraries approach this but they mostly seem to have some custom concatenation scripts. Is there a simpler solution? Seems like it should be a common enough use case.

Comment: Can you create a minimal test case with just a few files (on GitHub or plnkr or wherever) that demonstrates what you're trying to do and what goes wrong? Also, what version of browserify?

Answer (score 0):

Try what you're already doing with standalone and external, then when you bundle the second time pass the `noParse` option to browserify (e.g. `browserify({noParse: ['/abs/path/to/first/bundle']})`). Or you could try minifying the first bundle. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28176927/1034448).

Comment: The problem is that the first bundling (of the lib) should only resolve internal dependencies, I don't want a bunch of external libraries baked into mine. Then when the entire app is bundled, there are still dependencies in the lib that have to be resolved.

Comment: If the library as well as the app have underscore as external dependency and they are bundled separately and entirely (resolving all require calls) I would end up with a bundle that contains the underscore code twice.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to do. "If the library as well as the app have underscore as external dependency...I would end up with a bundle that contains the underscore code twice." No, you'd end up with a bundle that contains the underscore code zero times. Where do you want underscore to come from? Is it supposed to be in either bundle? If not, how do you intend to load it?

Comment: I want Underscore to be resolved in the App context, i.e. during the 2nd "bundling", by the consumer of the library. I simply want to bundle my library components into the typical `dist/singleFile.js` without the bloat of external dependencies. Or is that the common way to do it, shipping all external dependencies as part of the dist file?

Comment: Do you want underscore's code in the second bundle?