# React and Browserify: Cannot find module ./focusNode

Tags: .net, gruntjs, reactjs, browserify

I am using Browserify within Grunt to compile jsx files, and am getting a consistent error whereby the browserify task fails with the following error;

> > Error: Cannot find module './focusNode' from 'C:\project\src...'

I have one jsx component:

```
var React = require('react');

var createBooking = React.createClass({
   render: function () {

    return (
        <div className="Booking">
            <div className="col-xs-12 noPadding">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">{this.props.data.title}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                     This is a modal
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
});

module.exports = createBooking;
```

And then one main JS file;

```
var React = require('react');

(function (React) {

    var Booking = require('../dist/components/CreateBooking.js');

    var render = function () {
        React.render(React.createElement(Booking, { data: { title: 'Test' } }, document.getElementById('bookingForm')));
    };

    render();

})(React);
```

And finally my gruntfile (shortened for brevity);

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    browserify: {
        react: {
            options: {
                    transform: [
                        [require('grunt-react').browserify, {global: true}]
                    ],
                    debug: true
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'Scripts/components',
                src: ['**/*.jsx'],
                dest: 'Scripts/dist/components',
                ext: '.js'
            }]          
        },
        dist: {
            files: {
                './Scripts/dist/main_built.js': ['Scripts/custom/main.js']
            },
            options: {
                debug: true,
                paths: ['./node_modules','Scripts/custom/**', 'Scripts/dist/**']
            }
        }
    },
});
```

I am assuming the error is to do with paths somewhere, but I can't figure it out. Any clues?

Comment: What's in `dist/components/CreateBooking.js`?

Comment: Just the CreateBooking.js, which was compiled from a separate folder via Browserify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment is a bit hard to understand, but I believe you're saying `CreateBooking.js` is a Browserified bundle. If that's the case that likely explains your error: the new bundling operation is parsing that bundle for `require()` calls that don't need to, and can't be, resolved. See my answer here: [Browserifying libraries that were themselves browserified: relative paths error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078425/browserifying-libraries-that-were-themselves-browserified-relative-paths-error/28176927#28176927).

Comment: Indeed this does seem to be the problem. I haven't found a satisfactory solution to this, so I have resorted instead to having all files with *.jsx, so that they can all be Browserified in one pass. Not idea, but it works for now.