# How to use browserify standalone option

Tags: browserify, commonjs, umd

I'm trying to create a standalone library that can be used as global variable, amd or commonjs module.

But after compiling it with browserify with `standalone` option, I can't include it in a next build as a compiled library because of the browserify error

```
Error: Cannot find module './dependency'
```

How to handle this problem.

All source code that i use can be found here: https://github.com/paveltyavin/double-browserify

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem described in this [github issue](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/374) and in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078425/browserifying-libraries-that-were-themselves-browserified-relative-paths-error).

TLDR: use [derequire](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/derequire).

Browserify parses compiled code and tries to make bundle everytime it reads function `require` . Minification (uglify) can be a nice workaround to handle the problem.