# Module cannot be found when attempting to use custom ES6 Phaser.Plugin in a project

Tags: gruntjs, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs, phaser-framework

I am attempting to write a [new phaser plugin](https://github.com/JTronLabs/phaser-dynamic-state-transition) and am having issues with ES6 class imports across files. The current setup builds fine, and you can see the output [here](https://github.com/JTronLabs/phaser-dynamic-state-transition/blob/master/dist/phaser-dynamic-state-transition.js). However, when I  try to use the compiled plugin in an actual Phaser game...

```
import '../plugins/phaser-dynamic-state-transition';
```

My linter picks up the error

```
Cannot find module './TransitionStateManager' from '~/src/plugins'
```

From this, I know that it is successfully finding the built ES5 plugin and attempting to import it into the game. Also, it is successful when there is only 1 file in the plugin's src. The problem arises in-game when a second file is added, TransitionStateManager, even though it compiled fine.

Any ideas on why this is occurring?

Edit:

You can see all of the code in the GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/JTronLabs/phaser-dynamic-state-transition). However, for convenience here is my Gruntfile.js

```
  module.exports = function (grunt) {
   grunt.initConfig({
      pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

      //allow import/export of JS classes
      browserify: {
         dist: {
            options: {
               transform: [ //transform ES6 code to ES5 code
                  ["babelify", {
                     loose: "all"
                  }]
               ]
            },
            files: {
               "./dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js": ["./src/index.js"]
            }
         }
      },

      //turn the output js file into a minified file (use less kB)
      uglify: {
          dist: {
              files: {
                  "./dist/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js": ["./dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js"]
              }
          }
      },

      //define the watch task: build when you save an edit
      watch: {
         scripts: {
            files: ["./src/*.js"],
            tasks: ["build"]
         }
      }
   });

   grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-browserify");
   grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");
   grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-uglify");

   grunt.registerTask("build", ["browserify","uglify"]);//define the modules that will run in the build task
   grunt.registerTask("default", ["build","watch"]); //build and then start watching the files for changes
};
```

Edit:

I run `grunt` and the source files are bundled and output to a file. I take that file, copy it over to my game project's `src/plugins` folder. In my `src` folder I have the file `Preload.js`, which has the line `import '../plugins/phaser-dynamic-state-transition';`. At this point I have Gulp errors telling me `'./TransitionStateManager'` is missing.

Edit:

I'm currently using this [transition plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phaser-state-transition) from NPM, and I've found that if I download it directly [from the source](https://github.com/cristianbote/phaser-state-transition/blob/master/dist/phaser-state-transition.js) and try to reference it, I have the same errors...even though it works fine from NPM.

Working: 1. `npm install phaser-state-transition --save` 2. Consume via`import 'phaser-state-transition';`

Not Working: 1. [Download the source](https://github.com/cristianbote/phaser-state-transition/blob/master/dist/phaser-state-transition.js) 2. Consume via `import '../plugins/phaser-state-transition';`

[image]

Edit:

SO, it works if I use the minified version (built with the uglify plugin), on both the GitHub repo and my own repo. No idea why this works and the non-minified one does not though.

Comment: Could you include your browserify configuration in your question?

Comment: Updated. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: You mention you are trying to use the compiled plugin (do you mean the built bundle?); how are you trying to use/consume it?

Comment: Yes, the built bundle, sorry I don't know all the terminology haha. I updated my post. Thanks for the good questions!

Comment: @cartant, I got it working by using the uglify task to produce a minified file. However, I imagine this will make for difficult debugging. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: @James Is the phaser game that consumes the plugin also being Browserified? Usually this happens when you try to Browserify something that pulls in a Browserify bundle, for reasons I explain in [substack/node-browserify#1151](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/pull/1151). Minification is one solution, as you discovered and as I mention there and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28176927/1034448). You could derequire it instead for less disruption to the source (and you should if you're going to distribute it), or use source mapping with the minification.

Comment: Wow @JMM thank you for the help! Great readings. If you want to submit something as the answer I'll mark you as accepted.

Comment: @JMM bump (added characters)

Comment: Thanks @JamesLowrey! I think there's some kind of canonical answer feature here on SO...I should look into that and see if I can create one for this and point all the questions to it, since they can each sound very different but have the same root cause.

Comment: Thank would be awesome. Unfortunately I don't know how to help, but that sounds like a good idea to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when a previous Browserify bundle (your plugin) is in the dependency graph currently being Browserified (your game). In short, Browserify doesn't recognize that the previous bundle is now self contained and tries to resolve the `require()` calls in it. You can see my more detailed description in [substack/node-browserify#1151](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/pull/1151).

Possible solutions are:

- derequire the previous bundle (your plugin). This is also what you'd want to do if you're going to distribute the plugin.
- minify it, as you discovered.
- Use the `noParse` option when doing the second bundle (the game).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/28176927/1034448.